# How to check API's response time (performance) using Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I checked many answers for how I can check an API's response time using `startTime` and `endTime`. But is there any other way to find, using Xcode, where I can see the timing without writing code in API calling section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s another answer to consider:  write a unit test to measure the performance of your code.

```
class MyTestCase : XCTest
{
    func testMyAPI()
    {
        self.measure 
            {
                 // call your code here.
            }
    }
}
```

Here’s an article that covers using the measure block: [Continuous Performance Testing of an iOS Apps using XCTest](https://medium.com/xcblog/continuous-performance-testing-of-an-ios-apps-using-xctest-811df87fe227).

That article brings up some great pros and cons of this approach, and includes some sample code on GitHub.   I recommend you investigate this approach thoroughly, for even if it doesn’t fit your exact need today (it’s up to you), it surely is a great tool to have ready to employ in similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Xcode comes with Instruments, which has a Time Profiler tool.  You can launch Instruments from within Xcode using the Profile button.  Since you don't want to modify the code, instead you'd be using the Time Profiler tool to do regular sampling to see how much happens within each sample period.

See this [tutorial](http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/using-time-profiler-xcode-instrument-to-test-ios-application/) for details.

Comment: Thanks Smartcat I can see the time to call method but I can't see block based time. Like you know the method having block which takes around 2 seconds but I could not see. Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Using the Time Profiler definitely has its pros and cons. I’ve now posted a completely separate answer that may be more to your liking - and it has a block-based solution that you can run as a simple unit test. Hope that works better for you!